# How to share Text post to Facebook directly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook, post, share

Simple how can direkly open Facebook app to share text and link. without open popup

I have test many plugin but all not work like what I need.

[image]

without this popup need to share direkly to Facebook.

this what I test but not work as expect

```
var url = 'facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php';
    final Uri launchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'https',
      path: url,
      query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
        'text': 'test text - ' + postImagelink.toString(),
      }),
    );
```

or like

```
 String fbProtocolUrl;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      fbProtocolUrl = 'fb://';
    } else {
      fbProtocolUrl = 'fb://';
    }

    String fallbackUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/stories/create';

    try {
      Uri fbBundleUri = Uri.parse(fbProtocolUrl);
      fbBundleUri.query!=encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
        'text': 'test text - ' + _postImagelink.toString(),
      });
      var canLaunchNatively = await canLaunchUrl(fbBundleUri);

      if (canLaunchNatively) {
        launchUrl(fbBundleUri);
      } else {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(fallbackUrl),
        
            mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
      }
    } catch (e, st) {
      // Handle this as you prefer
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set up a button for opening a link, that is Facebook link, NOT a share button.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.stackoverflow.com  its work like this but how to add some text ?

Comment: @Enes there is no way any more to add your own custom text. Facebook offered a `quote` parameter to _suggest_ a quote to share to users for a while, but that has been removed again. If people want to write a custom text with their link share, they have to write it themselves.